# Titanium Alloy - Empty a node (view / window)

Tags: titanium-alloy

I am figuring my way around Alloy (slowly !).

I would like to know if there a way we can easily destroy and remove all the UI elements with a node ? Do we have anything like ?

```
view.empty()
```

What I am trying to do is, when a tab is loaded, I want the view to insert a Label "loading ..." and should be removed after the data is ready.

Coming to my 2nd question: How do I delete a node ?

```
view.delete() ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something basic : There is always a parent child relation between the Views(nodes as you say), to delete a view you need to have a handle at its parent view.

For your first Question :
you can check [This](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/78311/removing-all-child-objects-from-a-view) link.It will remove all child elements of a View.

For your second Question :
to delete a single view you have to do something like `ParentView.remove(childView)`

And yes [Activity Indicator](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ActivityIndicator) can be used to show a loader with/without message.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks this definitely helps. Although for some reason, I noticed, while node has children, node.children (= 0) while node._children (= correct value). Any reason why ?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an Activity Indicator, here are the docs: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ActivityIndicator